# Android development - The purpose of nested graph in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I know the nested graph allow us to divide screens into multiple nested set so that screens which are related can be grouped together and by doing so, it introduces clean navigation structures. However, I found that this kind of navigation is possible in jetpack compose.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            TutorialTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val home = "home"
                    val main = "/main"
                    val main1 = "/main/1"
                    val main2 = "/main/2"
                    val profile = "/profile"
                    val profile1 = "/profile1"
                    val profile2 = "/profile2"
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = home) {
                        composable(home) {
                            FakeComponent(
                                path = home,
                                onClick = { navController.navigate(profile2) })
                        }
                        navigation(startDestination = main1, route = main) {
                            composable(main1) {
                                FakeComponent(
                                    path = main1,
                                    onClick = { navController.navigate(profile2) })
                            }
                            composable(route = main2) {
                                FakeComponent(
                                    path = "/main/2",
                                    onClick = { navController.navigate(profile2) })
                            }
                        }
                        navigation(startDestination = profile1, route = profile) {
                            composable(profile1) {
                                FakeComponent(
                                    path = profile1,
                                    onClick = { navController.navigate(main1) })
                            }
                            composable(route = profile2) {
                                FakeComponent(
                                    path = profile2,
                                    onClick = { navController.navigate(main1) })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the main1 node, I am able to navigate to profile1 node, and vice versa. I don't see why this is allowed. Since they are of different child branches, they shouldn't be accessible. If this is allowed, I don't see any points of doing nested graph since we are freely navigate to every node we want.

Maybe I missed some points here. Please do enlighten me.

I need to clarify the usage of nested graph. I do know that it provides some other functionalities such as automatically navigate to startDestination, let's say if we define it. However, the situation I mentioned above makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's useful if you want to automatically manage app tabs, in that case you can use a navigation() block for each Tab and create a hierarky of "internal" routes. [There are a tutorial in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav) to implement that precise case.

IMHO the strangest thing is this: You can define the same child route at the same time inside different navigation(). In this case, the NavController will prefer that one insde you current navigation(), otherwise the first